# Finding rows with DBNull.Value from a Data Table using Select statement

Tags: c#

I have a data table with only one column containing strings. What is the best way to get a collection of rows having DBNull.Value using DataTable.Select() method?

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable("names");
DataColumn newColumn = new DataColumn("Name", System.Type.GetType("System.String")
{
AllowDBNull = true
};
DataRow row1 = dataTable.NewRow();
row1["Name"] = "John";
dataTable.Rows.Add(row1);
DataRow row2 = dataTable.NewRow();
row2["Name"] = DBNull.Value;
dataTable.Rows.Add(row2);
```

I tried *dataTable.Select("Name is null")* and it returned row2. But aren't null and DBNull.Value different as in null meaning an invalid reference and DBNull.Value representing a non existent value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to check if a Data Table has a null value in it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4604414/best-way-to-check-if-a-data-table-has-a-null-value-in-it). Or specifically with `Select()`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9324088/1132334

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
var NullRows = dataTable.Select("[Name]=''");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
var nullRows = dataTable.Select("[Name] is null");
```

Another option is to use LINQ

```
var query = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(r => r.Field<string>("Name") == null);
```

*Make sure that you add the column to your `DataTable`*

```
dataTable.Columns.Add(newColumn);
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you also please clarify if null and DBNull.Value are the same when using the select statement?

Comment: @KrishnaveniBujaranpally, yes.